# Converting data in column in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, derived-column

I'm writing an SSIS package to load data from a .csv into a db.

There's a column in the csv file that is supposed to have a count, but the records sometimes have text, so I can't just load the data in as an integer. It looks something like this:

[image: sample column]

I want the data to land in the db destination as an integer instead of a string. I want the transformation to change any text to a 1, any blank value to a 1, and leave all the other numbers as-is.

My attempts have so far included using the Derived Column functionality, which I couldn't get the right expression(s) for it seems, and creating a temp table to run a sql query through the data, which kept breaking my data flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three approaches you can follow.

#### (1) Using a derived column

You should add a derived column with the following expression to check if the values are numeric or not:

```
(DT_I4)[count] == (DT_I4)[count] ? [count] : 1
```

Then in the derived column editor, go to the error output configuration and set the error handling event to `Ignore failure`.

Now add another derived column to replace null values with `1` :

```
REPLACENULL([count_derivedcolumn],1)
```

You can refer to the following article for a step-by-step guide:

- [Validate Numeric or Non-Numeric Data in SQL Server Integration Services without the Script Task](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3605/validate-numeric-or-nonnumeric-data-in-sql-server-integration-services-without-the-script-task/)

#### (2) Using a script component

If you know C# or Visual Basic.NET, you can add a script component to check if the value is numeric and replace nulls and string values with `1`

#### (3) Update data in SQL

You can stage data in its initial form into the SQL database and use an update query to replace nulls and string values with `1` as follows:

```sql
UPDATE [staging_table]
SET [count] = 1
WHERE [count] IS NULL or ISNUMERIC([count]) = 0
```

Comment: I used your code for the derived column + the guide, I got it to work but I have a bit of a monster of a dataflow, though it at least does what I need it to. Time to learn some C# to cut out all these extra steps. Thank you!